# Why can I access a file from my web server even though viewing the directory URL is a broken link?

Tags: url, links, broken-links

I'm trying to understand how I'm able to access a PDF file from my website: `/Documents/Publications/2015/file.pdf` when `/Documents` comes up as a broken link.  It appears to be non-existant.

1. Why can I still access the file?
2. How can I find out what other files reside in the parent directories?

Comment: Is this on your site? Or other websites?

Comment: "a broken link" - In what way "broken"? A 404 or 403 or something else?

Comment: On another website - and it comes up with a 404 error message. My intent isn't malicious, it's mainly out of curiosity. The file I'm able to gain access to was a useful publication on network recon, I just wondered if there were any other useful publications within that directory I could access too.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://superuser.com/q/1139676/151741)

Answer (score 1):

1. URLs do not need to map directly onto the filesystem of the computer the HTTP server is running on.
2. You can't unless the server tells you, and it doesn't appear to. There might not even be a parent directory.